# begin transaction and commit transaction in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

If I Enclose a query between Begin Transaction and commit transaction in MS SQL, what will happen if i abort or stop the execution of the query. Will all the changes that had been done during executing ROLLBACKED.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your code. As long as your transaction exist, all changes will be pending a rollback or a commit.

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896531/806549).

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction can remain open until you call something like `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` or `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, or until SQL takes some action on it.

More info:

- [SQL Server and connection loss in the middle of a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978372/sql-server-and-connection-loss-in-the-middle-of-a-transaction)
- [What happens to an uncommitted transaction when the connection is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539564/what-happens-to-an-uncommitted-transaction-when-the-connection-is-closed)
- [What happens if you don't commit transaction in a database (say SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896479/what-happens-if-you-dont-commit-transaction-in-a-database-say-sql-server/4896531#4896531)

I actually like to take advantage of this when testing large updates or corrections. You can have something like this:

```
-- BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
-- COMMIT TRANSACTION

/*
    A bunch of SQL code here
*/
```

Then you can highlight/run the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then run the whole script. If you're happy with the results, you can highlight/run the `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. If not, run the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. Since those lines are commented out, they don't affect your overall transaction unless you explicitly highlight and run them.

Answer (score 0):

No. Transaction will still be active - you didn't rollback after all, did you? :)
Run this example and see what happens. If you break during transaction, you'll see value 2 is in a table, but you have to rollback or commit.

```
select 1 as x into #xxx 
GO


begin transaction

    insert into #xxx(x) select 2
    -- ctrl+break before time runs out.
    waitfor delay '00:00:10'

commit transaction


-- now try this:
select * from #xxx
rollback transaction
select * from #xxx
```