# what will happened if i dont call transaction.close or transaction.rollback?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, sql-server-express

In the begin of the unit of work I call to session.BeginTransdaction
I noticed that even if no changes where done to the DB during the transaction the commit is still expensive.

**What will happen if in case of no changes I just call session.close and I don't call transaction.commit? Does the transaction still dispose?**

Comment: Could you explain how the Commit is expensive? How did you measure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the sources of `NHibernate 3.1.0` and it seems that calling the `ISession.Close()` should result in a `ITransaction.Dispose()` for the default implementation. But nevertheless using that in an existing application did **not** result in a explicit transaction `commit` or `rollback` - checked with the `NHibernate Profiler`.

I don't think it is a good idea to leave the transaction to rely only on the `ISession.Close()` as it can lead to unpredictable behaviors. What if someone will adapt that particular method and include the `ISession.SaveOrUpdate`... your entities will not get persisted.

**UPDATE**:

From the `Sql Server` perspective I think it depends on your transaction `isolation level` but I'm pretty sure that sooner or later you will encounter locks or timeouts. Please refer to this `sql-server` specific question:

[What happens to an uncommitted transaction when the connection is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539564/what-happens-to-an-uncommitted-transaction-when-the-connection-is-closed)

Comment: I dont concern from abuse. My concern is the database. The database will have transaction that wasnt close (i think so).