# Breaking a connection to SQL Server halfway through an execution

Tags: sql-server, transactions, connection

If I execute a script against SQL, which has multiple transactions in it, but break the connection half way through, what does SQL do? Does it run the script to completion, or just roll-back the transaction it was currently in (or finish it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SQL Server detects that a connection is broken, it should rollback any current transaction and abort the current batch<sup>1</sup>.

Any preceding committed transactions will still be committed.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here I'm trying to draw the distinction between *scripts* and *batches*. Many client tools support scripts containing multiple batches (delimited by `GO`s) and its the batches that get submitted to SQL Server, sequentially.

Comment: Thanks Damien. Also the distinction between scripts and batches weren't so clear to me. Is it the client that breaks the script into separate batches and submits them separately then?

Comment: @MarkRoworth - yes, it is. That's why if you e.g. write code in another language and send it to the server, it doesn't recognise `GO`. That's the convention that the client tools use to know where to split the script into batches.

Answer (score 0):

Only committed transactions will be executed.

Other ones will do a roll-back.

Comment: Can you provide a documentation link for this?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html

Point 3.2 User-Defined Transactions.

Comment: And also, i think this question is a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539564/what-happens-to-an-uncommitted-transaction-when-the-connection-is-closed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: `Only committed transactions will be executed on the SQL server` This statement does not sounds right.

Comment: Ok... Sorry for my bad English )

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends, if there are multiple transactions in the script SQL, do you put commit into each transaction ? for example, if your script like this

```
BEGIN TRAN --Transaction 1
    INSERT TableA VALUES(value1,value2)
COMMIT TRAN

BEGIN TRAN --Transaction 2
    INSERT TableB VALUES(value1,value2)
COMMIT TRAN
```

if your sql server disconnected, half-way of the execution of the whole script, but while on the way of execution of the script and the sql server has completed transaction 1, and that's committed, then transaction 1 is completed, and you can see the result on tableA, but when the sql server running transaction 2 imidiately and few moment later the transaction 2 yet incomplete and the connection gets down, transaction 2 will be rollbacked, so you cant see the result on TableB