# How to set CommandTimeout

Tags: c#, smo, sqlcommand, command-timeout

I am using  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`.

My Code:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection( new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

I want to set `CommandTimeout` for it like we do with normal `SQLCommand`

Please tell me how to set `CommandTimeout` for queries running through `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.statementtimeout.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

You can set command timeout using the SMO object as shown below:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(ConnectionString));
server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 10800;
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

For more information on SMO object command timeout refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.statementtimeout.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

[how to set the query timeout from SQL connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198951/how-to-set-the-query-timeout-from-sql-connection-string)

Comment: i know how to set commandtimeout with sqlcommand.. but i don't know how to assign that command to Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server

Comment: did you try to set ConnectTimeOut in ServerConnection, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.connectionsettings.connecttimeout.aspx