# How to add CommandTimeout to connection string in web.config

Tags: web-config, timeout, connection-string, connection-timeout

How to add CommandTimeout to connection string in web.config?

I tried:

```xml
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123;Connect Timeout=200" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

and this:

```xml
<add name="MyProject.ConnectionString"  
         connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;CommandTimeout=60;User ID=sa;Password=saPassw0rd"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but it didnt' work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set the query timeout from SQL connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198951/how-to-set-the-query-timeout-from-sql-connection-string)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I made it like this:

```cs
private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public LinqToSql() : this(new MyDbContext())
    {
    }

    private LinqToSql(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.CommandTimeout = 500; 

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know there is no global way of setting Command timeout property, you have to set CommandTimeout property individually for each command object you create.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the timeout in a setting and refer to that value when the command timeout is set.
In config under appSettings add a key for CommandTimeout:

```xml
<add key="ContextCommandTimeout" value="500" />
```

Then in your code:

```cs
int cmdTimeout = -1;
string timeoutSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContextCommandTimeout"];

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeoutSettings)) 
{
    int.TryParse(timeoutSettings, out cmdTimeout);
}

if(cmdTimeout >=0)
    _context.CommandTimeout = cmdTimeout;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those still interested, as of about October 2020 it looks like this might be possible with .NET EF Core.

> With the latest 2.1.0 preview 2 release of the open source .NET client
> driver for Microsoft SQL Server and Azure SQL Database,
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, it is now possible to set the default
> command timeout via the connection string.
>
> Now you can work around timeout issues simply by changing the
> connection string, where this previously required changes to code, and
> maybe changes to code you did not have the ability to change.
>
> This could be an issue when you were using third party tools like
> Entity Framework Core migrations or EF Core database reverse
> engineering (scaffolding).

Refer:
https://erikej.github.io/sqlclient/2020/10/26/sqlclient-commandtimeout-preview.html

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume this is a .NET web-app, since it looks like one & it wasn't specified in the description / tags. This works for an app I've been developing, sets the DB command timeout to be 15 seconds:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=<DB>;
                         uid=<usr>; pwd=<pw>; default command timeout=15;" 
       providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The default command timeout is applied app-wide to each individual DB request. As far as I'm aware, [the default is 30 seconds if this isn't specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout). For a web-app, individual DB commands that take longer than 30 seconds is a bit extreme though; you may be better served having a rethink of how you architected the solution.

Comment: It should be noted that this only works because the MySql ConnectionStrings element allows that property.  Its not available for MSSQL for instance (so not supported using System.Data.SqlClient)

Comment: It doesn't work for SQL Azure

Answer (score -6):

If you want to put it into your web.config, you need to add a space. Try:

```
Command Timeout=60;
```

instead of:

```
CommandTimeout=60;
```

Comment: It doesn't work when adding to SqlClient provider connection string, I am getting: ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'command timeout'

Comment: SQLConnection objects appear to have a command timeout, but not for the ConnectionString: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.commandtimeout?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8.1