# Getting Timeout expired Error, have no access to Code base

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config

I am supporting application which executed a stored procedure the stored procedure is taking more than 3 minute to execute and give result.
The application which is using this Stored procedure on button click getting failed due that 3 minute waiting period. 
I have no access to the code base and can't extend command time property.Being not able to access code is there any way i can override sql commandtimeout property for ASP.Net code from WebConfig file to make the application work fine ??

Comment: Instead of trying to override the timeout try to solve the *real* problem - why does the stored procedure take so long? Are there any missing indexes? What does Activity Monitor or SQL Server Profiler show when running this stored procedure?

Comment: [There's no command timeout setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198951/how-to-set-the-query-timeout-from-sql-connection-string) in the connection string