# CommandTimeout for SQL Connection string

Tags: sql-server

How do I configure `CommandTimeout` (not `Connect Timeout`) from connection string in SQL Server?

I thought it'd be simple to find but apparently not. Below I added `CommandTimeout=60`. It doesn't seem to break anything, but I have no idea if it's actually working or not (and I can't find doc on this)

```
Data Source=someplace.com;Initial Catalog=MyDB;CommandTimeout=60;User Id=someID;Password=secret;
```

Comment: it's per command. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198951/how-to-set-the-query-timeout-from-sql-connection-string

Comment: muratgu  thanks i read that post, but I need to figure out a way (If it exists) from connection string, not SqlCommand

Comment: @user3761555 You can see all the available properties at [SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8). There is no command timeout available. Perhaps if you [edit] your question to explain the problem you are trying to solve we could help.

Comment: You ***CANNOT*** set the command timeout in the connection string. You need to specify it on the `SqlCommand` object at runtime

Comment: Tip: If you want to make the command timeout configurable then place it in a separate entry in the appSettings section of your config, and make the code read the timeout value from there, instead of hard-coding it into your application

Comment: The reason why I didnt just set SqlCommand.CommandTimeout is: My project depends on another util project shared by many. In that util project, we use Dapper. I dont want change in that base util project at this point. Thus, looking for an easy way out: If i can set it in connection string, that'd be perfect.

Comment: Thanks yall, for the confirmation.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably worth pointing out that setting the default command timeout via the connection string **is** possible in **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** since version ~2.1.0. This package is the open source replacement for System.Data.SqlClient and is available [from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient)

If you add e.g. `;Command Timeout=300` to your connection string and receive an error *Keyword not supported: Command Timeout'* you should check that you truly are using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and that its version is greater than 2.1; the question was posed before it was possible, but times have changed

Answer (score 0):

Confirm, using the versions of:

- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library

The CommandTimeout - when set for the Connection object - works also for the ADO Queries following Connection Open.